# Определить разрешение ролика через Python

Tags: python, видео

Требуется определить разрешение видео ролика перед тем как его отправить на обработку. Как это сделать через Python?

Comment: [Прежде чем задать вопрос, убедитесь, что вы выполнили тщательный поиск ответа. Поделитесь результатом вашего поиска и расскажите, что вы нашли и почему найденные ответы вас не устроили](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Информация о видео ролике через Python3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/891642/%d0%98%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-python3)

Comment: Рабочих вариантов не нашел, а многие просто копируют коды с хабра не проверив его на работоспособность

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import cv2
file_path = "./video.avi"
vid = cv2.VideoCapture( file_path )
height = vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
width = vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
```