# Информация о видео ролике через Python3

Tags: python, subprocess

Пытаюсь выдернуть информацию о разрешении видео ролика, но выдает ошибку. Помогите разобраться где косяк.
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
    import re
    import ffmpeg

```
def getvideodetails(filepath):
    cmd = 'ffmpeg -i %s" % filepath'
    p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    di = p.communicate()
    for line in di:
        if line.rfind("Video") > 0:
            resolution = re.findall('(\d+x\d+)', line)[0]
    return (resolution)


getvideodetails("D:\Документы\проекты\заготовки\1.mp4")
```

Выдает:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/htpthd/bin/probnik/разрешение.py", line 15, in <module>
    getvideodetails("D:\Документы\проекты\заготовки\1.mp4")
  File "D:/htpthd/bin/probnik/разрешение.py", line 10, in getvideodetails
if line.rfind("Video") > 0:
TypeError: argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Для такой задачи лучше использовать не ffmpeg, а ffprobe

Answer (score 1):

Судя по ошибке `TypeError: argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'`, у вас в `line` находятся байты, а не строка.

В `rfind` передавайте байты, пример:

```
...
if line.rfind(b"Video") > 0:
...
```

---

Другим вариантом будет указание кодировки, чтобы получить результат в строке:

```
p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Теперь вот что выдает: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'resolution' referenced before assignment

Comment: @SacredSacred, у вас `resolution` создается внутри цикла в `if`, а после возвращается из функции, а что если в `if` код не зашел? Вот это у вас и произошло. Как вариант, сразу вместо `resolution = re.findall('(\d+x\d+)', line)[0]` делайте выход из функции: `return re.findall('(\d+x\d+)', line)[0]`, а `return (resolution)` замените например `return ""`